# Can't stop requestAnimationFrame (Javascript/html5: canvas)

Tags: html, loops, canvas, requestanimationframe

I'm having trouble with quiting/killing/exitting my requestAnimationFrame. My gameloop works, i can pause my game (gameloop stays active). But when I want to return to my menu, I want to kill the requestAnimationFrame, so it stops drawing and updating. I've searched on the internet and stackoverflow, found similar questions tried te response, but no luck :(

```
var fps = 60;
var now;
var then = Date.now();
var interval = 1000/fps;
var delta;  

//============================================================================

function gameloop(){
window.requestAnimationFrame(gameloop);

if (game.isUnpaused()){
//game is not paused, update all
      now = Date.now();
          delta = now - then;

              if (delta > interval) {
                  then = now - (delta % interval);
              //DO ALL WHAT'S NEEDED: draw avatar,move obstacles,move avatar....
                  }}

//what to do when game is paused:
else{//draw stuff when game is paused}

}
```

Can Anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop a requestAnimationFrame recursion/loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735922/how-to-stop-a-requestanimationframe-recursion-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var active = true;
function gameloop(){
    if(active){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(gameloop);
        }
    }
```