# How can I restart my game when I press ENTER?

Tags: javascript, reload, keypress, onkeypress

I have made a simple game and it's almost done, the only thing I have left is to make the game restart when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now the game starts when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> but it doesn't restart.

Can someone help me please?

this is the code that starts the game

```
document.onkeydown = function tast (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {  // høyre
            høyre = 1;  
        } 
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {  // venstre
            venstre = 1;  
        } 
        if (e.keyCode == 38) {  // opp 
            opp = 1; 
        } 
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {  // ned
            ned = 1;              
        } 
        if(e.keyCode == 32) {
            newskudd();
            snd.play();
            console.log("hit space")
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            spill();
        }

}
```

to see a demo click the link [DEMO](http://elevweb.akershus-fk.no/~stmo0403/it2/spill/)

the spill(); function is

```
function spill() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (var i = 0; i < kuler.length; i++) { 
        kuler[i].x += 0;
        kuler[i].y += kuler[i].dy;


        ctx.fillStyle = kuler[i].f;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(kuler[i].x, kuler[i].y, kuler[i].r, 2*Math.PI, 0);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        if (venstre == 1){
            kuler[0].x -= 4;
        }
        if (høyre == 1){
            kuler[0].x += 4;;
        }
        if (opp == 1){
            kuler[0].y -= 4;
        }
        if (ned == 1){
            kuler[0].y += 4;
        }


        if (kuler[0].x >= canvas.width-kuler[0].r) {
            kuler[0].x = canvas.width-kuler[0].r
        };
        if (kuler[0].x <= 0+kuler[0].r) {
            kuler[0].x = 0+kuler[0].r
        };
        if (kuler[0].y >= canvas.height-kuler[0].r) {
            kuler[0].y = canvas.height-kuler[0].r
        };
        if (kuler[0].y <= 0+kuler[0].r) {
            kuler[0].y = 0+kuler[0].r
        };



    for (var j = 0; j < fiender.length; j++) { 
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(fiender[j].x, fiender[j].y, fiender[j].r, 2*Math.PI, 0);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        fiender[j].y += fiender[j].vy;

        if (fiender[j].x >=  canvas.width -fiender[j].r) {
            fiender[j].x =canvas.width - fiender[j].r;
        };
        if (fiender[j].x  <= 0 + fiender[j].r) {
            fiender[j].x =0 + fiender[j].r;
        };  

        if (fiender[j].vy >= 2) {
            fiender[j].vy = 2;  
        };


        /*if (fiender[j].y + fiender[j].r >= kuler[i].y && fiender[j].x + fiender[j]. == kuler[i].x) { // remove kuler[i] and fiender[j] } 
            fiender.splice(j, 1);
            kuler.splice(i,1);
        };*/

        var distanceFromCenters = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(fiender[j].x - kuler[i].x),2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(fiender[j].y - kuler[i].y),2 )); // you have a collision
        if (distanceFromCenters <= (fiender[j].r + kuler[i].r)) {
            fiender.splice(j, 1);
            kuler.splice(i,1);
            poeng += 1;
        } else if (fiender[j].y > canvas.height) {
            fiender.splice(j,1)
        }

        if(j > 1){ 
            fiender.splice(j,1)

        }       

        tekst.innerHTML = ( "Poeng: " + poeng  )
    }
}
    requestAnimationFrame(spill);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that name `høyre` will be supported everyhwere?

Comment: høyre is just the name of the direction i norwegian

Comment: everything works ecsept the restat kode

Comment: I had a quick look at your demo, `spill()` is called as expected every time enter is pressed. This causes the game to speed up before it ends, and seemingly has no effect afterwards. Either way, it would seem the problem is not in the code you've posted here.

Comment: @morten as adam said, `enter` key works just fine, but has unintended effects. You need to post the `spill()` function so we can take a look. Most likely you need to reset variables and `clearTimeouts()` so timers are reset.

Comment: i have now edited the post so you can see the spill(); function at the bottum

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is each time you press `spill()` you're starting a new `requestAnimationFrame` loop. Therefore, each time you press `spill()`, you're effectively double calling your `y coordinate` transformation: `fiender[j].y += fiender[j].vy;`

[Read here on how to properly start/stop a window.requestAnimationFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735922/how-to-stop-a-requestanimationframe-recursion-loop)

```
var requestId;

function loop() {
    ...
    // do stuff
    ...
    requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
}

function start() {
    if (!requestId) {
       loop();
    }
}

function stop() {
    if (requestId) {
       window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
       requestId = undefined;
    }
}
```