# JavaScript: requestAnimateFrame get faster

Tags: javascript

I have an animation with requesetAnimationFrame And when I replay it, it gets faster and faster until it gets invisible.

```
function tirer(){

    var missile=document.getElementById("missile");
    var currt= missile.currentStyle ||window.getComputedStyle(missile);
    if ( parseInt(currt.bottom)<700)
    missile.style.bottom=parseInt(missile.style.bottom)+20+"px";
    else
    alert ( "in top");


}
function animation (){
    tirer();
    requestAnimationFrame(animation);

}
```

How can I get it to be a stable, constant speed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling fps with requestAnimationFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764018/controlling-fps-with-requestanimationframe)

Comment: yes that aswered ! thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You probably call `animation()` multiple times (e.g. whenever a button is clicked).

Each call to `animation()` starts a new repeating `requestAnimationFrame()` -> `animation()` -> `requestAnimationFrame()` -> `animation()` -> ... sequence.

E. g. if you call `animation()` two times, your have two such sequences running and your framerate will double.

You need to cancel the currently ongoing request for an animation frame before sending a new request. See [How to stop a requestAnimationFrame recursion/loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735922/how-to-stop-a-requestanimationframe-recursion-loop)